# Google Geocoding Access Denied Error

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

One of our clients has started to get an access denied error on their site. Here is the error:

There was an error with Google's Geocoding Service: `REQUEST_DENIED`

Exception Details: System.ApplicationException: There was an error with Google's Geocoding Service: REQUEST_DENIED

Stack Trace: 
    [ApplicationException: There was an error with Google's Geocoding Service: REQUEST_DENIED]
    GoogleMapsAPIHelpers.GetGeocodingSearchResults(String address) +337
    FindAStoreCoatings.btnSearch_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +67
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +155
    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804

Basically it has all of a sudden has stopped working as of a week ago.  And their requests hadn't hit over the 2,500 free requests per day and they have the billing setup to pay for any days that go over that amount.

Does somebody have an idea on what to check for?

Comment: Try to raise this in the public issue tracker https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/. Hopefully somebody from Google can look into this.

Comment: If you already filed the ticket in the public issue tracker, please comment here the link. So that other people here can also know the updates for that issue.

Comment: Thanks - I added a ticket to the public issue tracker.  Here is the link - https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9895

Answer (score 1):

Always check the "error_message" field in JSON (or tag in XML) response, there should be an explanation here. It could be "The provided API key is invalid." if the API key has been deleted from your project, or something else if there's something off with project itself.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the info.  We did figure out the issue.  We found out that the client had changed IP addresses and that was the reason the API key wasn't working properly and why we were getting the "Request Denied" error.